# Prove that $\frac{1}{2} (e^R - e^{-R}) \geqslant \frac{1}{4} e^R $ with $R > 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, exponential-function

Sorry to bother you with silly question, but I can't figure out how to prove:

$$\frac{1}{2} (e^R - e^{-R}) \geqslant \frac{1}{4} e^R $$

with $R > 0$. I tried different ways but  that didn't lead me anywhere. Can you give me some hints, or help me prove it ? Thanks

Comment: Why would you think that the statement is true? Despite the constraint, what if $R=0$? What if $R$ is close to zero?

Comment: This statement is used in an exercise book to prove that an integral is zero at the limit of $R \to +\infty$, so for this reason I think is true. And yes, I see that is not for R close to 0, so I don't know what to say. This all starts by prove that $|{cosh(R + iy)| \geqslant \frac{1}{4}} e^{R} $ for $R>0$ and $y \in [0 , \pi]$

Comment: This inequality is true for large enough $R$ so you can use it to prove a statement with $R \to +\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying throughout by $4e^R$ to get

$$2(e^{2R})-2\ge e^{2R}\iff e^{2R}\ge2\iff2R\ge\ln2$$

Comment: So it's true for $R \geqslant \frac{ln 2}{2}$, not in general for $R>0$. Anyway, this is really useful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It isn't true.  Note that for $R=0$ the left side is $0$ and the right side $1/4$.  Since both sides are continuous, that inequality persists for some $R > 0$.

Comment: So, if I use this inequality in a limit for $R \to + \infty$ I have no problem ? Furthermore, can you explain your second affirmation ?

Comment: It is true for $R \to +\infty$, actually for $R \ge \ln(2)/2$ as Lab Bhattacharjee wrote.